# Serialization of graphic objects

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, gdi+

I have a complex shape. Application allows to draw any count of this shapes.
Then I must save that picture as XML file. How can I save them on XML file?
My .xml is created but there is only information like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.intertech.com")]
public  class ComplexShape
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int a; // large elipse width/2
    int b; // large elipse height/2
    Form1 fr;
    float angle;
}
private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            // Configure the look and feel of the save dialog.
            saveDlg.InitialDirectory = ".";
            saveDlg.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
            saveDlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
            saveDlg.FileName = "MyShapes";

            if (saveDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                XmlSerializer xml_serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ComplexShape));
                using (Stream fstream = new FileStream(saveDlg.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    xml_serializer.Serialize(fstream, complexShapes);
                    fstream.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("serialized");
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
```

complexShapes is Array of ComplexShapes, they creating and drawing on the Button click.

Comment: You need to define properties on `complexShapes` for the Xml serializer to work.

Comment: XML serialization doesn't serialize *private* members of a class.  Unlike binary serialization.  Also, the [Serializable] attribute only matters for binary serialization.  Do keep in mind that you can never get a Form class serialized, something you'll have to deal with when you deserialize a shape.  It doesn't exactly belong in that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class ComplexShape
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int a; // large elipse width/2
    int b; // large elipse height/2
    Form1 fr;
    float angle;

    [XmlAttribute()]
    public int X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public int Y { get { return y; } set { y = value; } }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public int A { get { return a; } set { a = value; } }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public int B { get { return b; } set { b = value; } }
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public Form1 Form { get { return fr; } }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public float Angle { get { return angle; } set { angle = value; } }

}

public class Drawing
{
    List<ComplexShape> shapes = new List<ComplexShape>();

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public List<ComplexShape> Shapes { get { return shapes; } }

    [XmlArray("Shapes")]
    public ComplexShape[] ShapesArray
    {
        get { return shapes.ToArray(); }
        set { shapes = new List<ComplexShape>(value); }
    }

    public void Save(string fname)
    {
        XmlSerializer xml_serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Drawing));
        using (Stream fstream = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            xml_serializer.Serialize(fstream, this);
            fstream.Close();
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Drawing dwg = new Drawing();
        dwg.Shapes.Add(new ComplexShape());
        dwg.Shapes.Add(new ComplexShape());
        dwg.Shapes.Add(new ComplexShape());
        dwg.Shapes.Add(new ComplexShape());

        dwg.Save("ComplexShape.xml");
    }
}
```

with output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Drawing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Shapes>
    <ComplexShape X="0" Y="0" A="0" B="0" Angle="0" />
    <ComplexShape X="0" Y="0" A="0" B="0" Angle="0" />
    <ComplexShape X="0" Y="0" A="0" B="0" Angle="0" />
    <ComplexShape X="0" Y="0" A="0" B="0" Angle="0" />
  </Shapes>
</Drawing>
```